# How to turn off force fields for rigid bodies?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

How can I switch off a certain force field for only some of my dynamic rigid bodies in the scene without keyframing “Dynamic” and have the objects which were affected by force field still interact in a dynamic way with the ones that weren’t.

Comment: With particles, a force field affects particles that are on the same layer. Can you separate your objects by layer?